# EF Code First Migrations creating extra foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create a `Profile` table to integrate with the Asp.Net Identity table: `AspNetUsers`. I'm using Code First Migrations with EF 6.0.

Here is my User class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {

        }


        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Profile class:

```
public class Profile
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the configuration in my DataContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
                .HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(m => m.ApplicationUser);
```

The weird thing is that when I run the migration it creates ApplicationUserID and ApplicationUser_Id in the database when all I want is to create ApplicationUserID and use that as the foreign key column. If I add the property AppliationUser_Id it'll add ApplicationUser_Id1. Anyone know how to fix this?

**I want to make sure that the Foreign Key is on the profile table i.e. Profile has the column ApplicationUserID and not vice versa i.e. I don't want the AspNetUsers table to have a profile_ID column.**

P.S. I'm using Fluent API, not data annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure an one to one relationship, Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent must be used as the foreign key.

```
public class Profile
{
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Now, about the FK convention,  due to that restriction, since there is no choice, Code First will just infer the FK for you.

Another thing is, the proper way to configure one-to-one relationship using Fluent Api is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
            .HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(m => m.ApplicationUser)
            .WithOptional(a=>a.Profile);
```

Comment: I ran the configuration you wrote and I got ApplicationUserID and ApplicationUser_Id on the Profile table

Comment: That should be because EF doesn't see `ApplicationUserID` as PK for that entity.Are you specifying explicitly a PK property to your `Profile` entity ?

Comment: To make sure that you are using `ApplicationUserID` as PK use this configuration: `modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasKey(t => t.ApplicationUserID);`

Comment: I added this to make sure that Profile has a primary key set: 
            modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasKey(x => x.ID);

Comment: The ApplicationUser class is just inherited from the IdentityUser in asp.net Identity and it's primary key is ID.

Comment: As I explained before, the PK of `ApplicationUser` must match with the PK of `Profile`, this is a restriction in a one to one relationship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100085/discussion-between-eitan-and-octavioccl).

Comment: Thanks for the help!!