# Error when using Custom User class inherited from IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, basic-authentication

I am using asp.net core 2.2. 
When using a custom class for app user inherited from IdentityUser, register & password sign-in fails with message "SqlException: Invalid column name 'ApplicationUserId'."

**Statrup.cs**

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**Application User class**

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {  
 }
```

The database is standard identity generated with no custom columns added.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661544/ef-code-first-migrations-creating-extra-foreign-key

Comment: Have you run migrations and update database to sync up your model and database? Is there any detail steps to reproduce your issue? For the error message,  you used `AccountController` which is in .net core 2.0 identity. For .net core 2.2, the default identity is library with `LoginModel`. Have you migrated from .net core 2.0 to .net core 2.2?

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your ApplicationDbContext like this:

```cs
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

Your default ApplicationDbContext is using `IdentityUser` as its user storage not `ApplicationUser`.